# (Jetpack Compose) Как правильно посчитать значение паралакса?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Я делаю вью с паралакс эффектом и чтоб когда юзер скролит вниз, появлялся actionbar так же как описано в этой статье

https://proandroiddev.com/parallax-in-jetpack-compose-bf521244f49

Делаю это вот так

```
@Composable
fun HeaderBarParallaxScroll() {
    val scrollState = rememberScrollState()
    Box {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .verticalScroll(scrollState),
        ) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(500.dp)
                    .background(Color.White)
                    .graphicsLayer {
                        Log.e(
                            "scroll",
                            "${scrollState.value.toFloat()}, max = ${scrollState.maxValue}, ratio = ${(scrollState.value.toFloat() / scrollState.maxValue)}"
                        )
                        alpha = 1f - ((scrollState.value.toFloat() / scrollState.maxValue) * 1.5f)
                        translationY = 0.5f * scrollState.value
                    },
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
            ) {
                Image(
                    painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground),
                    contentDescription = "tiger parallax",
                    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
                )
            }

            repeat(100) {
                Text(
                    text = "MyText",
                    modifier = Modifier.background(
                        Color.White
                    ),
                    style = TextStyle(
                        color = Color.Red,
                        fontSize = 24.sp
                    )
                )
            }
        }

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .alpha(min(1f, (scrollState.value.toFloat() / scrollState.maxValue) * 5f))
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(60.dp)
                .background(Color.Yellow),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.CenterStart
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "Header bar",
                modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 16.dp),
                style = TextStyle(
                    fontSize = 24.sp,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.W900,
                    color = Color.Black
                )
            )
        }
    }
}
```

И вроде бы все работает, но проблема в том, что значения насколько быстро будет уезжать паралакс и насколько быстро будет появляться actionbar зависит от высоты контента.

Как видно в примере вот тут я под изображение добавляю 100 текстов

```
repeat(100) {
                Text(
                    text = "MyText",
                    modifier = Modifier.background(
                        Color.White
                    ),
                    style = TextStyle(
                        color = Color.Red,
                        fontSize = 24.sp
                    )
                )
            }
```

и все работает, но если 100 поменять на 1000, то паралакс медленнее реагирует и что самое главное для того, чтоб появился actionbar нужно пролистать пол списка вниз

Как это сделать, чтоб правильно работало? Нужно, чтоб отклик паралакса и отображение actionbar не зависило от высоты контента, хоть это 100 текстов хоть 1000 должно работать одинаково

Comment: Также работа с `scrollState.value` направшивается на использование `derivedStateOf `

Comment: @vitidev я только начал использовать Jetpack Compose, поэтому не совсем понял, что вы имеете ввиду

Comment: `scrollState.value` это стейт. и его чтение в коде планирует рекомпозицию. Когда у вас скрол уедет вниз, то `alpha` станет `1f`, а `scrollState.value.toFloat()` будет продолжать планировать рекомпозицию, хотя результат все равно будет `1f`. Степень появления этих дополнительных рекомпозиций зависит от структуры кода, но вообще для этого случая придуман [derivedStateOf](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects#derivedstateof)

Answer (score 1):

`(scrollState.value.toFloat() / scrollState.maxValue) * 5f` высчитывает прозрачность в зависимости от позиции скрола.
Но почему то при этом завязано на общую высоту. Общая высота `scrollState.maxValue` разная, а потому и результат выражения разный.

А значит чтобы всегда было фиксированное значение нужно  зависеть только от `scrollState.value`, а остальные значения должны быть константами.

Что-то вида `scrollState.value.toFloat() / 5000) * 5f`

ps: Вместо константы в общем случае правильнее завязываться на высоту картинки, чтобы к моменту ухода картинки была полная непрозрачность, и от него получить нужное число для деления.

Comment: Я в итоге привязался к высоте экрана `val screenHeight = with (LocalDensity.current) { LocalConfiguration.current.screenHeightDp.dp.roundToPx() }`, не уверен, что к высоте картинки получиться нормально привязаться, так как она тоже с паралаксом, то есть она уходит с экрана медленее

Comment: Высота скрола - величина переменная, поэтому и при разной высоте контента разная скорость прозрачности получается. Высота экрана - тоже величина переменная (просто не с таким размахом, поэтому и разница менее заметна). Для постоянности нужна константа. Высота картинки - константа. Другое дело, что получить ее высоту неизвестно как, а зашить высоту в ресурсы не сильно отличается просто от константы в коде. Просто "пусть на таком значении скрола уже все" - тоже константа.